# Open PDF after creating with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, printing, ghostscript

I have created virtual PDF printer using ghostscript as described here http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~henrik/GSWriter/GSWriter.html
Steps:

1. installing ghostscript
2. installing redmon
3. adding HP Color Laserjet 4550 PS printer to redirected port
4. printer port settings:
   Redirect this port to the program:

C:\Program Files\gs\bin\gswin32c.exe

Arguments for this program are:

@"C:\Program Files\gs\pdfwrite.txt" -sOutputFile="%1" -c .setpdfwrite -f -

Output:

Promt to filename

Run:

Hidden

1. creating configuration file pdfwrite.txt:

   ```
    -I"C:\Program Files\gs\lib";"C:\Program Files\gs\fonts"
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite
    -r600
    -dNOPAUSE
    -dSAFER
    -sPAPERSIZE=a4
    -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4
    -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress
    -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage
   ```

All work fine, but I want automatically open created PDF file after it created. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

RedMon is responsible for the flow of control in this case, so you will have to modify RedMon to take an action after conversion.

Possibly you could modify the execution of Ghostscript to run a batch file instead, and have the batch file execute Ghostscript and then launch it on the newly created file. One problem with this is that you have set the properties to 'prompt for filename', and I don't see any way to pass the filename into an external batch program. Note; according to the RedMon documentation you can't do this on Windows Server, because of permissions problems running cmd.exe.

So you would need to modify the RedMon application, the source code should be available at the location you downloaded RedMon from.

Answer (score 0):

> *Possibly you could modify the execution of Ghostscript to run a batch file instead, and have the batch file execute Ghostscript and then
>   launch it on the newly created file*

How great idea!

> *One problem with this is that you have set the properties to 'prompt for filename', and I don't see any way to pass the filename into an
>   external batch program*

It is easy! See below.

Virtual printer port settings:

---

**Redirect this port to the program:**
C:\Program Files\gs\pdfwrite.bat

**Arguments to this program are:**
"%1"

**Output:** Prompt for filename

---

Then we create pdfwrite.bat:

---

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\bin\gswin32c.exe" @"C:\Program Files\gs\pdfwrite.txt" -sOutputFile="%1" -c .setpdfwrite -f - 
"1"
```

---

Then... click File/Print in any application, choose your virtual printer, choose filename  and...hurray! PDF-file is opened!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is useful a little correction.
On Windows 7, I do the last line of the batch file as "%1" (not simple "1"),
and then it works opening the last pdf created:

```
"C:\gs\gs9.15\bin\gswin32c.exe" @"C:\gs\pdfwrite.rsp" -sOutputFile="%1" -c .setpdfwrite -f - 
"%1"
```

Bye.